# What is the best approach to find the nearest line segment (x1,y1), (x2,y2) from a point (x,y)?

Tags: computational-geometry

Let's suppose the are three line segments in a plane, each line segment has coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). What is the best approach to find out the nearest line segment from a point (x, y)?

Hint: use vectors dot product.

Comment: Do you need nearest line segment or segment on nearest line? Those two are different in general case. The solutions below seem to address the latter.

Answer (score 3):

The distance from a point to a line is given by the projection of a line from the point to some point on the line onto a unit vector orthogonal to the line.

First we need same data.

```
lines = Partition[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 2}], 2]
point = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]
Graphics[{Line[lines], PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[point]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Then we need unit vectors orthogonal to our lines:

```
ortho = Normalize /@ (Subtract @@@ lines).{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}};
```

The distance from the point to the lines is now given by the absolute value of the projection of the line from `point` to the start of the lines onto the orthogonal unit vector:

```
dist = MapThread[(Abs[(point - #1).#2]) &, {lines[[All, 1]], ortho}]
(*{0.0292868, 0.260295, 0.347937}*)
```

It is obvious, for our example, that the first line is closest to the point.

Comment: in `ortho` replace `dat` with `lines`.

Comment: @rmw. Thank you, embarrassing!

Comment: no, we're human, luckily!

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about the problem in geometric terms. The given point and the two points defining any one of the lines form a triangle. One of the altitudes of that triangle is the distance from the given point to the chosen line. So the problem reduces to finding the relevant altitudes of three triangles and selecting the shortest one.

In V12, Wolfram introduced the function `TriangleConstruct` into *Mathematica* which, when given a list of tree points (coordinate pairs) representing a triangle, can compute many properties of that triangle. One of those properties is its altitude.

Once we have the altitudes for thee triangles, we can order the altitudes by length and use the ordering to identify the line we are looking for.

Here is some code that does what I have described.

```
SeedRandom[6]

pt = {0, 0}; (* the given point *)
lines = Partition[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 2}], 2];
triangles = {pt, #[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ lines;
altitudes = TriangleConstruct[#, {"Altitude", pt}] & /@ triangles;
ordering = OrderingBy[altitudes, Apply[EuclideanDistance, First[#]] &];
lines[[ordering[[1]]]] (* the line closest to the given point *)
```

> ```
> {{0.446885, 0.440912}, {0.612913, -0.86427}}
> ```

Here is a visualization of the geometry created by the above code.

```
Graphics[
  {InfiniteLine /@ lines,
   {Dashed, altitudes},
   {AbsolutePointSize[8],
     {Red, 
        Point[pt], 
        TriangleConstruct[triangles[[ordering[[1]]]], {"Foot", pt}]},
     {Black, Point /@ lines}},
     Block[{x1, x2},
       {x1, x2} = (lines[[ordering[[1]]]][[#]] & /@ {1, 2});
       {Text[Style[#, 8], # + {.28, .05}] & /@ {x1, x2}}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, Automatic},
   PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, .2}, Automatic},
   Frame -> True]
```

[image: scene]

**Notes**

- Fixing the given point at the origin induces no loss of generality.
- The red point from which the three (dashed) altitudes radiate is the given point.
- The other red point is the foot of the shortest altitude.

Answer (score 1):

For three line segment instead of infinite line. Here we use `Line` instead of `InfiniteLine`.

```
pairs = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {3, 2, 2}];
pt = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 2];
result = {Line[#], RegionNearest[Line[#], pt], 
    RegionDistance[Line[#], pt]} & /@ pairs
point = TakeSmallestBy[result, Last, 1][[1, 2]];
Graphics[{Line /@ pairs, {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pt]}, 
  Line[{pt, point}], {PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[point]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: because OP asked for nearest line segment, I think you want to use `Min`, not `Max`, and you need to identify which segment is the nearest.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks your advice.